# How do I (partially) reverse engineer the COUNTIF(range, condition) function?

Tags: google-apps-script, simplify

I'm trying to learn Google Apps Script and have just tried to emulate the functionality of the built-in COUNTIF function. This is the code I have so far:

```
//function that has the same functionality as the built-in COUNTIF(>range<, true)

var numberTrue = 0;

function numTrue(input) {
   return Array.isArray(input) ?
     howMany(input) :
     //Error("Invalid parameter"); //how to throw an error?
     "Invalid parameter";
}

function howMany(inputArray){
   inputArray.map(row => row.map(cell => condition(cell))); //how does this work?
   return numberTrue;
}

function condition(input){
   if (input == true){
   numberTrue++;
   }
}
```

I have  <s>4</s> 3 main problems with this.

1. This code seems very clunky and I'm not sure how to streamline it. This is in part because
2. I do not know how to trace the line:

   ```
    inputArray.map(row => row.map(cell => condition(cell)));
   ```
3. I'm not sure how to throw an error. I would like to do this if the input value is not an array (see comment above).
4. <s>You cannot currently customize the condition parameter.</s>

Any feedback would be appreciated. This is also not urgent whatsoever; I'm just trying to improve my understanding of optimization and reverse engineering.

Comment: Handling all the possible criteria for COUNTIF is not an easy task.  Perhaps you have some specific ones you want to implement?

Comment: Ah that makes sense. In that case, scratch my 4th point. I can focus on optimizing what I have.